# How do I unzip a ".zip" archive and redirect the output a specified file using Perl?

Tags: shell, perl

Lets say I have a zip file called `myPartial.zip` and I want to unzip this `myPartial.zip` archive and redirect the output to a file called `output.txt`.

To achieve that I could use the following shell script:

```
unzip -Z1 myPartial.zip | grep -v "/$" >> my.log
```

My question is how do I do the same in Perl?

Comment: Have a look at [Archive::ZIP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Zip).

Comment: You want to append all the files in the zip archive to a single file? Should there be anything to indicate where one file ends and another starts in the output?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options for unzipping in Perl.

First one is to just run the shell command in Perl.

```
system 'unzip -Z1 myPartial.zip | grep -v "/$" >> my.log';
```

Next is use one of the zip modules. There are a few, including [Archive::Zip](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Zip), [IO::Uncompress::Unzip](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Uncompress::Unzip) and [Archive::Zip::SimpleUnzip](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Zip::SimpleZip).

Whether you need to get into using one of the modules depends on the requirements of what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so `unzip -Z1 foo.zip` appears to list the *filenames* of the files in the zip archive, not extract the files. That makes more sense for wanting everything in a single file. And you just want files, not directories.

So a perl one-liner:

```
perl -MArchive::Zip -E '$, = "\n"; say grep { m![^/]$! } Archive::Zip->new($ARGV[0])->memberNames' foo.zip >> my.log
```

But really, it's easier to just use `unzip`/`zipinfo` like you already are.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the shell command directly using the [`system`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) method:

```
system("unzip -Z1 myPartial.zip | grep -v "/$" >> my.log");
```

If you'd like to terminate your script after execution is complete use the [`exec`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) method:

```
exec("unzip -Z1 myPartial.zip | grep -v "/$" >> my.log");
```

If you want to handle the program's output directly in PERL, simply use the backticks to execute the command and get it's output:

```
$response = `unzip -Z1 myPartial.zip | grep -v "/$" >> my.log`;
```

You could then use [`print`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) to preview the output, like this:

```
print $response;
```

Good luck.